# When using scalebox to fit my algorithm in one page a random number appears

Tags: algorithms, scaling

Here's the code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
\scalebox{0.85}{
  \begin{minipage}{1.1\linewidth}
\caption{Inferir relação}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Objetivo
\Desc{Procura o caminho composto por segmentos de linhas de transmissão até }
\Desc{chegar a uma subestação/central geradora de energia.}
\EndObjetivo
\Input 
\Desc{Uma lista com todos os elementos de um circuito: relacao}
\Desc{Um objeto do tipo Point onde representa o extremo da linha a conectar: N} 
\Desc{Uma lista com todas as instalações próximas de N: S}
\Desc{Uma lista com todos os segmentos de linha próximos de N: L}
\Desc{Um objeto do tipo segmentoLinha onde contém o extremo da linha a}
\Desc{conectar N: segmentoLinha}
\Desc{Um inteiro com o número de circuitos que o segmento de linha tem: NC}
\Desc{Uma lista com os níveis de tensão: niveisTensao}
\EndInput
\Output
\Desc{Uma lista de ...}
\EndOutput
\Inicializacao
\Desc{Um \emph{container} onde armazena as relações \emph{relacoes} := None}
\EndInicializacao
\Desc{instalacaoComeco := relacao[0]}
\Desc{instalacao := CalculoUtil.intersecaoNoInstalacoes(N,S)}
\Se { }$instalacao$ == $None$
\Desc{instalacao := CalculoUtil.obterInstalacaoProxima(N,S)}
\EndSe

\Se { }$instalacao$ \textbf{e} $instalacao.osmID$ != $instalacaoComeco.osmID$
\Desc{relacao.append(instalacao)}
\Desc{relacao.append(NC)}
\Desc{relacao.append(niveisTensao)}
\Desc{\textbf{Retorna} list(relacao)}
\EndSe

\Repetir
\Desc{segmentoLinhaSeguinte := L.next()}

\Se { }$N.intersects(segmentoLinhaSeguinte)$ 
\Se { }$segmentoLinhaSeguinte.osmID == segmentoLinha.osmID)$ 
\EndSe
\Ou { } $segmentoLinhaSeguinte.existeNumaRelacao() == True$
\Desc{\textbf{continuar}}
\EndOu
\Se { }$N.intersects(segmentoLinhaSeguinte.verticeInicial)$ 
\Desc{noSeguinte := segmentoLinhaSeguinte.noVerticeFinal()}
\EndSe
\SenaoSe { }$N.intersects(segmentoLinhaSeguinte.verticeFinal)$
\Desc{noSeguinte := segmentoLinhaSeguinte.noVerticeInicial()}
\EndSenaoSe
\Senao
\Desc{\textbf{continuar}}
\EndSenao

\Desc{numeroCircuitos := max(NC, segmentoLinhaSeguinte.NC)}
\Desc{niveisTensao.append(segmentoLinhaSeguinte.niveisTensao)}
\Desc{segmentoLinhaSeguinte.ExisteNumaRelacao := True}
\Desc{relacaoCopia := relacao.copy}
\Desc{relacoes.extend(\textbf{Algoritmo4}(relacaoCopia.append(segmentoLinhaSeguinte),}
\Desc{segmentoLinhaSeguinte, noSeguinte, L, S, niveisTensao, numeroCircuitos))}
\Se { }$relacoes == None$ 
\Desc{\textbf{continuar}}
\EndSe
\Desc{\textbf{Break}}
\EndSe
\EndRepetir
\Ate { }L não ter mais elementos
\EndAte
\Se { }$relacoes == None$ 
\Desc{segmentoLinha.ExisteNumaRelacao := False}
\EndSe
\Desc{\textbf{Retornar} relacoes}
\end{algorithmic}
\label{inferirrelacao}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{algorithm}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

There's like a number one in the midle of the algorithm, how can i remove it?

Comment: You are putting a minipage (scaled) inside the algorithm environment. Try to scale the algorithm environment instead (or put the algo inna minipagw and then scale it)

Comment: IIRC, algorithmic can be put inside an `\hbox`.  `\caption`, not so much.